# R programming: plyr how to count values from a column with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to summarize the pass/fail status for my data as below. In other words, I would like to tell the number of pass and fail cases for each product/type.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
product=c("p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p1","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2","p2")
type=c("t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2")
skew=c("s1","s1","s1","s2","s2","s2","s1","s1","s1","s2","s2","s2","s1","s1","s1","s2","s2","s2","s1","s1","s1","s2","s2","s2")
color=c("c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3","c1","c2","c3")
result=c("pass","pass","fail","pass","pass","pass","fail","pass","fail","pass","fail","pass","fail","pass","fail","pass","pass","pass","pass","fail","fail","pass","pass","fail")
df = data.frame(product, type, skew, color, result)
```

The following cmd returns the total number of pass+fail cases but I want separate columns for pass and fail

```
dfSummary <- ddply(df, c("product", "type"), summarise, N=length(result))
```

Result is:

```
        product type N
 1      p1      t1   6
 2      p1      t2   6
 3      p2      t1   6
 4      p2      t2   6
```

The desireable result would be

```
         product type Pass Fail
 1       p1      t1   5    1
 2       p1      t2   3    3
 3       p2      t1   4    2
 4       p2      t2   3    3
```

I have attempted somthing like:

```
 dfSummary <- ddply(df, c("product", "type"), summarise, Pass=length(df$product[df$result=="pass"]), Fail=length(df$product[df$result=="fail"]) )
```

but obviously it’s wrong since the results are the grand totatl for fail and pass.

Thanks in advance for your advice !
Regards,
Riad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
dfSummary <- ddply(df, c("product", "type"), summarise, 
                   Pass=sum(result=="pass"), Fail=sum(result=="fail") )
```

Which gives me result:

```
  product type Pass Fail
1      p1   t1    5    1
2      p1   t2    3    3
3      p2   t1    4    2
4      p2   t2    3    3
```

Explanation:

1. You are giving the data set, `df` to the `ddply` function.
2. `ddply` is splitting on the variables, "product" and "type"

   - This results in `length(unique(product)) * length(unique(type))` pieces (i.e. subsets of the data `df`) split on every combination of the two variables.
3. With each of the pieces, `ddply` applies some function that you provide. In this case, you count the number of `result=="pass"` and `result=="fail"` there are.
4. Now `ddply` is left with some results for each piece, namely the variables you split on (product and type) and the results you requested (Pass and Fail).
5. It combines all of the pieces together and returns it

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed ! Thx for the prompt answer !

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `reshape2::dcast`.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(product + type~result,data=df, fun.aggregate= length,value.var = 'result')
##   product type fail pass
## 1      p1   t1    1    5
## 2      p1   t2    3    3
## 3      p2   t1    2    4
## 4      p2   t2    3    3
```

Comment: Much faster than ddply. Thanx :)